# TailwindCSS Dark mode not working in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I've been at this for a couple of days now and still can't seem to get this working. I'm trying to get the whole dark mode going with Tailwind CSS in Nuxt.js.

I think it may be an issue with the CSS setup and not the TypeScript side as I have a toggle that switches the `<hmtl></html>` class to light and dark.

As a reference, I've been trying to copy Fayazara's work which you can find [here](https://github.com/fayazara/nuxt-tailwind-darkmode).

Env:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Node 14.15.4
- NPM 6.14.10
- Nuxt.js 2.14.12
- TailwindCSS 2.0.2

Here are some of the config files:

**nuxt.config.js:**

```js
export default {
    head: {
        // meta stuff
    },
    purgeCSS: {    
        whitelist: ['dark-mode'],  
    },
    components: true,
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxt/typescript-build',
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxtjs/color-mode',      
    ],
    colorMode: {
        classSuffix: ""
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        darkSelector: '.dark-mode',
    },
    variants: {
        backgroundColor: ['dark', 'dark-hover', 'dark-group-hover', 'dark-even', 'dark-odd', 'hover', 'responsive'],
        borderColor: ['dark', 'dark-focus', 'dark-focus-within', 'hover', 'responsive'],
        textColor: ['dark', 'dark-hover', 'dark-active', 'hover', 'responsive']
    },
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss-dark-mode')()
    ]
}
```

**~/assets/css/tailwind.css:**

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

I have this in my settings page `<p class="bg-blue-500 dark:bg-red-500">Settings</p>` which stays blue even with the toggle

I uploaded my project to [GitHub](https://github.com/herbievine/bug-tracker) for all the other files

Thanks to anyone that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using a third party plugin to enable dark mode support. TailwindCSS 2.0 (Which you're using) supports dark mode on its own, so no need to add the plugin.

Change your `tailwind.config.js` to:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

That enables dark mode via the class `dark`.

Then in `layouts/default` you have:

```
<template>
    <div class="dark">
        <Navigation />
        <Nuxt />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Navigation from '~/components/Navigation.vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Default',
    components: {
        Navigation
    }
})
</script>
```

That `<div class="dark">` is making everything dark.

Remove that and everything will be light mode. Add it back and everything will be dark mode.

For more info see [Toggling dark mode manually](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually) from the TailwindCSS docs.